# Can not install VLC Media Player on Fedora 34

Tags: linux, fedora, vlc-media-player

when i try to install VLC  `# dnf install vlc` ,   i get these Errors:

```
Error: 

Problem: package vlc-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64 requires vlc-core(x86-64) = 1:3.0.16-1.fc34, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package vlc-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64 requires libvlccore.so.9()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides live555(x86-64) = 2020.07.31 needed by vlc-core-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64
  - nothing provides libx264.so.161()(64bit) needed by vlc-core-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64
  - nothing provides libx265.so.199()(64bit) needed by vlc-core-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64
  - nothing provides libfaad.so.2()(64bit) needed by vlc-core-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64
  - nothing provides libdca.so.0()(64bit) needed by vlc-core-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64  
  - nothing provides libBasicUsageEnvironment.so.1()(64bit) needed by vlc-core-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64
  - nothing provides libUsageEnvironment.so.3()(64bit) needed by vlc-core-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64
  - nothing provides libgroupsock.so.8()(64bit) needed by vlc-core-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64
  - nothing provides libliveMedia.so.79()(64bit) needed by vlc-core-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

I don't understand why it says **conflicting requests**

Then i tried to install the dependencies manualy:

`# dnf deplist vlc`

and got:

```
package: vlc-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: /bin/sh
   provider: bash-5.1.0-2.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: /usr/bin/sh
   provider: bash-5.1.0-2.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: dejavu-sans-fonts
   provider: dejavu-sans-fonts-2.37-16.fc34.noarch
  dependency: dejavu-sans-mono-fonts
   provider: dejavu-sans-mono-fonts-2.37-16.fc34.noarch
  dependency: dejavu-serif-fonts
   provider: dejavu-serif-fonts-2.37-16.fc34.noarch
  dependency: hicolor-icon-theme
   provider: hicolor-icon-theme-0.17-10.fc34.noarch
  dependency: libQt5Core.so.5()(64bit)
   provider: qt5-qtbase-5.15.2-16.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libQt5Core.so.5(Qt_5)(64bit)
   provider: qt5-qtbase-5.15.2-16.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libQt5Core.so.5(Qt_5.15)(64bit)
   provider: qt5-qtbase-5.15.2-16.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libQt5Gui.so.5()(64bit)
   provider: qt5-qtbase-gui-5.15.2-16.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libQt5Gui.so.5(Qt_5)(64bit)
   provider: qt5-qtbase-gui-5.15.2-16.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libQt5Svg.so.5()(64bit)
   provider: qt5-qtsvg-5.15.2-4.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libQt5Svg.so.5(Qt_5)(64bit)
   provider: qt5-qtsvg-5.15.2-4.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libQt5Widgets.so.5()(64bit)
   provider: qt5-qtbase-gui-5.15.2-16.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libQt5Widgets.so.5(Qt_5)(64bit)
   provider: qt5-qtbase-gui-5.15.2-16.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libQt5X11Extras.so.5()(64bit)
   provider: qt5-qtx11extras-5.15.2-3.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libQt5X11Extras.so.5(Qt_5)(64bit)
   provider: qt5-qtx11extras-5.15.2-3.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libX11.so.6()(64bit)
   provider: libX11-1.7.2-3.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libXext.so.6()(64bit)
   provider: libXext-1.3.4-6.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libXinerama.so.1()(64bit)
   provider: libXinerama-1.1.4-8.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libXpm.so.4()(64bit)
   provider: libXpm-3.5.13-5.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit)
   provider: glibc-2.33-20.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libfluidsynth.so.2()(64bit)
   provider: fluidsynth-libs-2.1.8-3.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libfreetype.so.6()(64bit)
   provider: freetype-2.10.4-3.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libfribidi.so.0()(64bit)
   provider: fribidi-1.0.10-4.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit)
   provider: libgcc-11.2.1-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.0)(64bit)
   provider: libgcc-11.2.1-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.3.1)(64bit)
   provider: libgcc-11.2.1-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libjack.so.0()(64bit)
   provider: jack-audio-connection-kit-1.9.17-1.fc34.x86_64
   provider: pipewire-jack-audio-connection-kit-0.3.33-3.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libm.so.6()(64bit)
   provider: glibc-2.33-20.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
   provider: glibc-2.33-20.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit)
   provider: glibc-2.33-20.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.29)(64bit)
   provider: glibc-2.33-20.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libpthread.so.0()(64bit)
   provider: glibc-2.33-20.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
   provider: glibc-2.33-20.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libpulse.so.0()(64bit)
   provider: pulseaudio-libs-14.2-3.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libpulse.so.0(PULSE_0)(64bit)
   provider: pulseaudio-libs-14.2-3.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libstdc++.so.6()(64bit)
   provider: libstdc++-11.2.1-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)(64bit)
   provider: libstdc++-11.2.1-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.8)(64bit)
   provider: libstdc++-11.2.1-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit)
   provider: libstdc++-11.2.1-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)(64bit)
   provider: libstdc++-11.2.1-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit)
   provider: libstdc++-11.2.1-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit)
   provider: libstdc++-11.2.1-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit)
   provider: libstdc++-11.2.1-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.29)(64bit)
   provider: libstdc++-11.2.1-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9)(64bit)
   provider: libstdc++-11.2.1-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libvlccore.so.9()(64bit)
   provider: vlc-core-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libwayland-client.so.0()(64bit)
   provider: libwayland-client-1.19.0-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: rtld(GNU_HASH)
   provider: glibc-2.33-20.fc34.i686
   provider: glibc-2.33-20.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: vlc-core(x86-64) = 1:3.0.16-1.fc34
   provider: vlc-core-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: xdg-utils
   provider: xdg-utils-1.1.3-9.fc34.noarch
```

I installed every single of them but still getting the first Error.

(I tried to install VLC on another Fedora 34 and did'nt get these Errors and it was installed successfully and working whithout any problem.)

My repo list:

````
fedora                                       Fedora 34 - x86_64                                          
rpmfusion-free-updates                       RPM Fusion for Fedora 34 - Free - Updates                             
updates                                      Fedora 34 - x86_64```
````

Comment: Just to be sure, did you try these as a root user?

Comment: Also, did you try dnf check-update and then trying to install VLC?

Comment: yes i did them both

Comment: Installing `vlc-core-3.0.16-1` will downgrade three packages. ... If you previously installed a package / other packages depending on {`libaom, libavif, libvmaf`}, then vlc cannot be installed. ......... Rpmfusion is not as compatible with Fedora, as it used to be years back.

Comment: @KnudLarsen what can i do? should i remove these three packages? doesn't this cause problems?

Comment: »» remove these three packages «« : No. `vlc` depends on {libaom, libavif, libvmaf}, but in an old "Fedora 19" version. ... Looks like the same package vlc is used for old EL7,,,, EL8 and Fedora. .... Solution : Remove the "video package(s)" depending on the three libs, or whatever is causing the issue. .... Download vlc-core https://mirror.netsite.dk/rpmfusion/free/fedora/releases/34/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/v/vlc-core-3.0.12.1-9.fc34.x86_64.rpm and report errors from an attempted install.

Comment: @KnudLarsen thanks. but can you help me to find why is causing this issue? I installed Fedora34 recently and I can't install vlc... I realy don't know what to do.

Comment: ? What is the error report from `dnf install vlc-core` ?

Comment: @KnudLarsen Same as `dnf install vlc`. I downloaded vlc-core.rpm and tried to install it `rpm -vi vlc-core-3.0.12.1-9.fc34.x86_64.rpm` but got the same error.

Comment: Please show in your question https://superuser.com/posts/1669465/edit .... the reply from the command `dnf install ./vlc-core` . .... And we are missing `dnf repolist` and `$ rpm -qa | sort > list1` . ......... You should be able to work out issues , when you have 2 x Fedora 34 . Use e.g.  `diff -u` to compare text lists from both OS.

Comment: ?Why don't you compare repolist in your two Fedora 34 installs ? ? ........ Enable missing repo's. This is my list: `fedora, fedora-cisco-openh264, fedora-modular, rpmfusion-free, rpmfusion-free-updates, updates, updates-modular` . .... You are missing at least one "enabled" : **rpmfusion-free** !